# Joining an additional table with belongsToMany()?

Tags: laravel-4, many-to-many

This question is best illustrated by an example:

```
users
    id
    name

roles
    id
    name

role_user
    user_id
    role_id
    rank_id
    group_id
    ...

ranks
    id
    name

groups
    id
    name
```

I can easily eager load a users table by specifying the following relationship in my `User.php` model:

```
public function roles() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
}
```

Which will output the table below when calling `User::with('roles')`:

```
User | Role
-------------
Jon  | Admin
Jan  | Mod
```

However I have no idea how to extend this to include:

```
User | Role  | Rank   | Group
-----------------------------
Jon  | Admin | Boss   | Blue 
Jan  | Mod   | Minion | Red
```

What I've tried doing `User::with('roles', 'ranks', 'groups')` but that is certainly wrong since I'm telling Laravel there are `rank_user` and `group_user` intermediate tables too but there aren't. What is the correct way?

PS: I know it's better to separate the ranks and groups into their own relationship/pivot tables, this is simply an example.

EDIT: Closest example I can find for this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2619#issuecomment-38015154

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just treat your model's relations methods as ordinary queries and build upon them:

```
public function roles() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('Role')
              ->join('role_user', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
              ->join('ranks', 'ranks.id', '=', 'role_user.rank_id')
              ->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'role_user.group_id');
}
```

Relations queries like the above are not so intuitive to understand when they get too complex, so it may be better to rethink database design, but in theory it's possible to manipulate them.

Comment: Thanks @tbuteler, I have tried something similar to this but I can't seem to select `rank/group` names. I've added the line `->select('ranks.name')` just above my joins but my rank names still aren't showing up. Can you update your answer to accommodate this?

Comment: I'm actually surprised that Laravel doesn't have an easy way to do this. I was expecting something like `->belongsToMany('role_user', 'Role', 'Rank', 'Group')`

Comment: Your `select` should have worked... Perhaps it's being overridden? Have you tried `->select('ranks.name as rank_name')` or some other alias?